# Will Ivy Bridge Xeon's be compatible with Sandy Bridge motherboards?

Tags: cpu, motherboard

I'm putting together a new server.  I'm looking at the Xeon E3-1270 processor.  I see that the the new ivy bridge line is coming out next week.  The ivy bridge version of this chip will be called Xeon E3-1270 v2 and it has the same socket.  Will the new E3-1270 v2 work with existing motherboards that are designed for the E3-1270? (I'm looking at the SuperMicro X9SCM-F)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to sources such as Anandtech, [Ivy Bridge will be backwards compatible with Sandy Bridge-based motherboards.](http://www.anandtech.com/show/4830/intels-ivy-bridge-architecture-exposed)

> Ivy Bridge is backwards compatible with existing LGA-1155
>   motherboards, although there will be a new chipset for Ivy Bridge and
>   new motherboards to enable some features (e.g. PCI Express 3.0, native
>   USB 3.0). The new chipset family falls under the 7-series banner.
>   We'll see Z77, Z75, H77, Q77, Q75 and B75 available at or around
>   launch.

Traditionally, Intel have featured backwards compatibility within each tick-tock cycle, and evidence points out this time it should be the same.

However, with the new Tri-Gate technology, and servers being a different class of machines, while there is a high chance it will be compatible (albeit maybe with lacking features), there is still a small chance it won't be compatible.

Ivy Bridge server class processors are not due out next week - their desktop processors are. According to Hardmac, there's a chance that [Ivy Bridge Xeons will be delayed](http://www.hardmac.com/news/2012/03/20/probably-no-xeon-ivy-bridge-in-2012).

Comment: That Hardmac article is about socket 2011 Xeons with quad-channel memory controller, no relation to the chip he's asking about.