# How to check if Xeon sandy bridge be replaced by ivy bridge

Tags: cpu, motherboard

We are running algorithms that would benefit from faster RAM. We currently have a Dell T5600 workstation with 1600mhz RAM, but with 2 CPUs that are limited to 1333 ([Xeon e5-2620](http://ark.intel.com/products/64594/Intel-Xeon-Processor-E5-2620-15M-Cache-2_00-GHz-7_20-GTs-Intel-QPI)).  The cheapest upgrade option could hypothetically be the [Xeon e5-2620 v2](http://ark.intel.com/products/75789/Intel-Xeon-Processor-E5-2620-v2-15M-Cache-2_10-GHz) (ivy bridge).

From reading this [Will Ivy Bridge Xeon's be compatible with Sandy Bridge motherboards?](https://superuser.com/questions/414183/will-ivy-bridge-xeons-be-compatible-with-sandy-bridge-motherboards) question from a few years ago it seems backwards compatible.  According to this [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LGA_2011)

> Original LGA 2011 socket is used for Sandy Bridge-E/EP and Ivy
>   Bridge-E/EP processors, while LGA 2011-1 is used for Ivy Bridge-EX
>   (Xeon E7 v2) CPUs

As well as [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ivy_Bridge_%28microarchitecture%29):

> Ivy Bridge processors are backwards compatible with the Sandy Bridge
>   platform, but such systems might require a firmware update (vendor
>   specific).

It seems that the newer version of the Xeon should be compatible, as intel also lists the socket as the same.

As I understand it, the caveat is the firmware must be updated.  How do you check if the firmware on a workstation is compatible with a newer microarchitecture? There does not seem to be many people with this situation online.  I would like to know if it is possible, but the most realistic way might be to just buy a new motherboard and get the latest architecture of the e5-2620 v3.

Comment: Have you checked for a model number on the motherboard?

Comment: Check the motherboard's product website.  It will literally list every CPU that it supports and what revision of the BIOS it requires to do so.  If its not on the list its not compatible.

Comment: Its a Dell motherboard for the T5600, as in, it has DELL written in big letters on it, but I dont see where they list which cpu it supports.  Maybe there is a different company number but i dont see it.